# How to expand items of form when maximizing window?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I have tried to use anchor to expand items of a form when user maximizes the window, but the result looks terrible, like this:
https://s22.postimg.org/a47f0ufwh/image.png

Original window:
https://s15.postimg.org/jzsa7sqgb/image.png

I use Anchor Top, Left, Right for buttons and lock them. Is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to "expand" or "shrink" `controls` in `winforms` is by using `Dock` property. `Anchor` will get you the some sort of expand and shrink, but like you said, it looks ugly.

However, if you are trying to keep your buttons to the left and labels to the right, you would want your `controls` to be `anchored` to `top`/`bottom` and `right` only, if you want the `control` to appear on the right; `top`/`bottom` and `left` only, if you want it sticking on the `left` and so on. If you `anchor` them in all directions, the `controls` will expand/shrink in all directions when the `form` changes.